# Prepping freshly machined block for building

Tags: engine, machining

I'm building an engine from the ground up to swap into my project car. The aluminium block has been re-lined with ductile iron sleeves so the machinist sprayed them with white grease to prevent rusting.

There may be metal dust still within the galleries and the bores need to be cleaned of the honing residue and white grease.

What is the best way to prep this engine for build? I'm worried that if I don't clean it well enough, the metal particles will cause damage to the bearings when built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most decent machine shops have a large parts washer... best cleaning of block I know of... had several done - came back like new, but you need to oil relevant surfaces quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have mentioned that the machinist recommended the block be hand cleaned. It did go through his parts washer when I originally delivered it, but since the sleeves have been fitted and honed it was just greased and given back to me.

Comment: Well, having had work done like that, my friendly machine shop always ran it through again... But I also removed oilway plugs etc...

Comment: OK, I will see if he can run it through the washer again when its build time - thanks :)

Comment: Always liked building a spotlessly clean block..

Comment: I'm looking forward to it!

Comment: What a parts washer won't do is chase all the oil lines/galleries in the block and crank. That is usually done by hand with a bottle brush of some sort. YMMV

Comment: Quick update: I have now arranged to build the short block at the machinist's workshop with his oversight. We will use acetone, white cloth and pipe cleaners to prep the block.